# Can I open MS Office 2016 Mac files on MS Office 2010 Windows computer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

I am making presentations on my Mac OS X at home. I am using MS Office 2016. The applications I am using are MS Word, MS PowerPoint and MS Excel.

Will there be a problem running these files on an MS Office 2010 on Windows 8?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.  All versions of PPT from 2007 onward use the same file format.

However, you might use fonts that aren't available on the Windows computer, which can cause text formatting problems. If I recall correctly, the Win box would have to have QuickTime installed if you've added any MOV movies to the presentation.  And if you use any 2016 features that aren't supported on 2010, they won't work but 2010 will either ignore what it doesn't understand or will "gracefully degrade".

Best bet:  try it to be sure.